# About the Event Viewer

Tags: python, windows, logging, event-viewer

I want to receive a warning in the event viewer whenever the system time is changed manually by a user. However, I've noticed that the event log also registers time changes when the system time is synced automatically. I want to ensure that the warning is triggered only for manual time changes. Could you please confirm if this is possible?